# Regex: Find all html tags that contain some other particular html tags

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have some html tags starting with `<p class="mb-40px">` and end with `</p>` The first tag has in it some other tags such as `</li>` `</ul>` `</div>` and `spaces` and `\n` as you can see.

```
<p class="mb-40px"></g></svg>               </a>
            </li>
             
        </ul>

    </div>
    </p>

    <p class="mb-40px">Foarte frumos lucru</p>
<p class="mb-40px">I love cars</p>
```

I want to find and delete all html tags such as the first one that contain `</li>` `</ul>` `</div>`

**The Output should be:**

```
    <p class="mb-40px">Foarte frumos lucru</p>
<p class="mb-40px">I love cars</p>
```

My solution is not good:

FIND: `(?=<p class="mb-40px">)[\s\S]*?</li></div>|</ul>[\s\S]*?</p>`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: so why are you using text editors? whats your workflow here? since your data is XHTML, you would normally use tools that support query languages like xpath to search, and tools like DTDs/XLST to transform documents, but that is a little more specialized than you are probably going to find in a text editor, even one as advanced as N++ or Sublime. VSCode would prolly do it though: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/how-to-execute-an-xslt-transformation-from-the-xml-editor?view=vs-2022

Comment: I am using notepad++ I am sure a regex will do the job

Comment: well, try to solve it and you will see how "simple" it is. I try to solve this for about 3 hours...

Comment: I know you got this recommendation on basically every question you write about RegEx + HTML, I'll put it here again anyways: [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/15087622)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all `<p class="mb-40px">` tags that contain only empty tags or spaces:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:<.+?>|\s)+?</p>\R*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="mb-40px"> # start tag
  (?:                 # non capture group
    <.+?>               # any tag
   |                   # OR
    \s                  # any kind of space
  )+?                 # end group, must appear 1 or more times, not greedy
</p>                # end tag
\R*                 # 0 or more any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks @Toto. Always the best.

Comment: I test your regex with a longer version, some other tags and text to be deleted before </p> . I try your regex, and in this new case doesn't work. Can you please update your answer also adding the 2 solution for this new longer case ?

https://regex101.com/r/IoO7M4/1

Comment: @JustMe: It is a completly different question, here you want to remove when there are tags or spaces. The other example there is more than just spaces. What do you want to delete, what are the rules? You should ask a new question.

Comment: Must be the same output as in the code above. The difference is that are more tags. Of course, I can post a new question, but it will be ban or deleted, because is very similar to this one. But the new formula,  if you find it, it will be a second option, and a better one.

Comment: @JustMe:All I can find is to delete **all** tags and their content except `<p...> ... </p>` without tags inside. Not sure it is what you want

Comment: yes @Toto. Exactly this .

Comment: @JustMe: [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/may6ag/1). Be aware that **all** your file will be deleted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135295/discussion-between-just-me-and-toto).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!.*(</p>)).*|\s+</p>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot @Hellena

Comment: This removes **all** tags other than `<p>...</p>` and `<p>` tags when `</p>` is not on the same line. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kNyXIM/1)

Comment: Some expressions for xml/html parsing `(<.*?>|[^<]+)\s*`   # Get tags and text `(\w+)="(.*?)"`    # Get attibutes

Answer (score 1):

Another solution more complete that can deal with other tags inside the
`<p class="mb-40px"> ... </p>`.

```
 <p class="mb-40px">[^<>]*</p>\R?(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/may6ag/1) with explanation.

Be aware that **all** your file will be deleted! Except `<p class="mb-40px"> ... </p>`

Comment: thanks a lot @Toto